# How I compile my server code on server?

Tags: java, sockets

I am new in socket programming. 
i have two java programs( Client.java and Server.java), For socket programming i want to compile my server.java code to server which always listen to socket, But i don't know what i do on server.

Server.java

```
import java.lang.*;
 import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;

 class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String data = "Toobie ornaught toobie";
  try {
     ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
     Socket skt = srvr.accept();
     System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
     System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
     out.print(data);
     out.close();
     skt.close();
     srvr.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
 }
  }
```

Client.java

```
    import java.lang.*;
     import java.io.*;
      import java.net.*;

      class Client {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   try {
     Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
     System.out.print("Received string: '");

     while (!in.ready()) {}
     System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it

     System.out.print("'\n");
     in.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: sorry,.. what's the question?

Comment: try reading the java doc on client server http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I want to run my server.java on server. after that every time when i run my run client.java it connects to my server.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on how to compile Java files. In your case it will be `javac Server.java` to compile it, and then `java Server` to run. The same goes for Client.

Comment: Ya, but when i compile my server code and mean time client code both communicate, after that connection close, and i again i call client its shows 'Connection refused', I want every time i compile code its get data from server or send data to server.

Answer (score 0):

Got it here.
http://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/socket/SocketBasic1.php

Here server always listen to client.
Thank you guys for help.